# Can anyone help out with this proof, certain steps are unclear. Norm of linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have the following norm defined as follows (in $R^n$, $x=(x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^n)\ $)$\| x\|_1= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x^i|$

Let $A:R^m \to R^n$ a linear map of the spaces $(R^m ,\| \cdot \|_1 )$ and $((R^n ,\| \cdot \|_1 )$. **Lets assess** $\|A\|_1$.

We have (taking into consideration the elements of the matrix $(a_i ^j)_{n \times m}$): $$\|Ax\|_i\leq \sum |x^i|\| Ae_i\|_1$$

then this transition is unclear for me:
$$$\|Ax\|_i\leq \left( \sup_{1 \leq i \leq m}\| Ae_i\|_1 \right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |x^j|\right) = \left(\sup_{1 \leq i \leq m} \sum_{j=1}^n |a_i^j| \right) \|x \|_1$$

Comment: Which step is unclear? The inequality or the equality?

Comment: The inequality is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|_1}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$As you write correctly, we have
$$ \norm{Ax} = \norm{\sum_{i=1}^n x^i Ae_i}
   \le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x^i} \norm{Ae_i} $$
Now, note that for every $i$, we have
$$ \norm{Ae_i} \le \sup_{1\le j \le n} \norm{Ae_j} $$
Let's call the supremum $S$, then $\norm{Ae_i} \le S$ for all $i$, giving above
$$ \norm{Ax} = \norm{\sum_{i=1}^n x^i Ae_i}
   \le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x^i} \norm{Ae_i}  \le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x^i}S $$
As $S$ is a constant for $i$, we may continue
$$ \norm{Ax} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{x^i} S = S \cdot \sum_i \abs{x^i} = S \cdot \norm x = \bigl(\sup_{1\le j \le n} \norm{Ae_j} \bigr) \cdot \norm x$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have a follow up question related to this one, which I will put the link in here. I'd like it very much if you could take a look at that aswell.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352676/proof-that-every-polilinear-map-whos-domain-is-rn-1-times-rn-2-time