# Proof that every polilinear map who's domain is $R^{n_1} \times R^{n_2}... \times R^{n_k}$ and co-domain any given real normed space Y is bound.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

A Polilinear map\operator is $P:X^1 \times ... \times X^n \to Y$ such that the foolowing applies: $\lambda, \mu \in R$

$$ P( \lambda x_1^1 + \mu x_2 ^1, x^2,...,x^n)= \lambda P(x_1^1,x^2,...x^n)+ \mu P(x_2^1,x^2,...x^n) \\...... \\\ ...... \\ P(x^1, x^2,...,\lambda x_1^n+ \mu x_2^n)= \lambda P(x^1,x^2,...x_1^n)+ \mu P(x_2^1,x^2,...x_2^n)$$

> Now the question at hand

Proof that every polilinear map who's domain is $R^{n_1} \times R^{n_2}... \times R^{n_k}$ and co-domain  any given real normed space $Y$ is bound with the following norms: $x=(x^1,x^2..,x^n)$

$$a.)\|x\|_{\infty}=\max{x^i}   \\b.) \|x\|_1 =\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x^i| \\ c.) \|x\|_2 =(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x^i|^2)^{1 \over 2} $$

The book gives the answer for $a.)$ which goes as follows:(the first inequality I don;t get) 
$$\| P(x_1^{i_1},x_1^{i_2},...,x_n^{i_n}) \| \leq \sum|x_1^{i_1}|... |x_n^{i_n}| \| P(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_n}) \|\\ \leq (\sum \| P(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_n}) \|)\|x^{i_1}\|_{\infty}...\|x^{i_n}\|_{\infty}$$

where the summing is done upon a finite number of possible n-torics $(e_{i_1}...,e_{i_n})$$e_{i_1}$-one of the coordinate vectors of space $R^{n_i}$

What I have difficulty imagining is the summing and the first inequality which I arrleady mentioned. I would greatly appreciate enlightenment on this matter and even more how $b.)$ and $c.)$ are done.  Link to a similar question I provide here: [Can anyone help out with this proof, certain steps are unclear. Norm of linear operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352608/can-anyone-help-out-with-this-proof-certain-steps-are-unclear-norm-of-linear-o/1352616#1352608)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

For a) Develop $P(x_1,\dots, x_k)$ for the first variable knowing that $$x_1=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} x_1^{i_1} e_{i_1}$$ and using linearity of $P$ for the first variable. You get

\begin{align}\vert P(x_1,\dots, x_k) \vert &= \left\vert P(\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} x_1^{i_1} e_{i_1},x_2, \dots,x_k) \right\vert\\
&=\left\vert  \sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} x_1^{i_1} P(e_{i_1}, x_2, \dots, x_k)\right\vert\\
&=\left\vert  \sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} \dots \sum_{i_k=1}^{n_k} x_1^{i_1} \dots x_k^{i_k} P(e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}, \dots, e_{i_k})\right\vert\\
&\le \left(\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} \dots \sum_{i_k=1}^{n_k} \left\vert P(e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}, \dots, e_{i_k})\right\vert \right) \Vert x_1 \Vert_\infty \dots \Vert x_k \Vert_\infty
\end{align}

Using triangular inequality and the definition of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ to bound the sum.

For b) and c) this is the consequence of the fact that on $\mathbb R^n$, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: "Then use the triangle inequality and the definition of..." I'm not seeing this leading to the last line, and can assume some coefficient is missing, but nevertheless boundedness is quite apparent. Only if it's not too much of trouble, add that last line.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I updated the answer to provide a bit more details.

Comment: Thanks, looks quite simple and clear when you type it out. :)